# How To Delete Desired Image Sizes From wp-content/uploads?

Tags: thumbnails, images

My default media setting in WordPress blog is **150x150**, **300x300**, **1024x1024** respectively for **thumbnail**, **medium**, **large** images. Now I am designing a theme that need different size thumbnail images to show in theme. For this, I go to the media setting again and changed the setting with my news sizes like **72x72**, **250x250**, **400x400** respectively for **thumbnail**, **medium**, **large** images.

But now to resize my old uploaded images, I used [**Regenerate Thumbnails**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) WordPress plugin and that generated my new media setting images size easily. So this solved my main problem.

### Main Question:

Now the main problem that just occurred is that my hosting space is now going to end. When I checked my files then found that I have **7** images of one image and from that I am only using **4**.

```
first-image-name.jpg
first-image-name-72x72.jpg
first-image-name-150x150.jpg
first-image-name-250x250.jpg
first-image-name-300x300.jpg
first-image-name-400x400.jpg
first-image-name-1024x1024.jpg
second-image-name.jpg
second-image-name-72x72.jpg
second-image-name-150x150.jpg
second-image-name-250x250.jpg
second-image-name-300x300.jpg
second-image-name-400x400.jpg
second-image-name-1024x1024.jpg
...............................
---------- and so on ----------
```

Now I want to delete **150x150**, **300x300**, **1024x1024** sizes images. For this many recommend me [**DNUI (Delete not used images**)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dnui-delete-not-used-image-wordpress/) and [**Clean Up Images**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleanup-images/) WordPress plugins but they are not picking those old image sizes.

*Q:) So How To Delete My Desired Image Sizes From `wp-content/uploads` folder?*

Comment: Use [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, Thanks. Please share this in answer so that I will select it correct...

Comment: Done. Glad that worked for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick and easy fix for this is to make use of a plugin called [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) (*to which I don't have any affiliation to*)

Unlike a plugin like Regenerating Thumbnails, Force Regenerate Thumbnails creates all your new custom sizes and delete all redundant/orphaned sizes.

> Force Regenerate Thumbnails allows you to delete all old images size and REALLY regenerate the thumbnails for your image attachments.

Comment: Glad it helped. I use this plugin a lot when experimenting with image sizes. :-)

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you running? I'm on 4.0.1 and it throws a ton of errors.

Comment: I haven't tested it on 4.0+. You should contact the plugin author if there is abug in the plugin so that he/she can get to work on that. :-)

Answer (score 8):

That's easy! If you have SSH access, log in and do the following for each size. I am just showing <kbd>150x150</kbd> size only.

Go to the desired uploads folder via command line.

```
cd /your-site.com/wp-content/uploads
```

Let's find if that size is available.

```
find ./uploads/*  -iname '*-150x150.*' -ls
```

If you see some images as the output then delete 'em with

```
find ./uploads/*  -iname '*-150x150.*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Do make sure you back up everything before running such a command.

Or you can search for all the resized images with this command

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*-[[:digit:]]{2,4}x[[:digit:]]{2,4}(@2x)?.(jpg|jpeg|png|eps|gif)" -type f
```

If there are any. Then you can delete them all with the following command

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*-[[:digit:]]{2,4}x[[:digit:]]{2,4}(@2x)?.(jpg|jpeg|png|eps|gif)" -type f -exec rm {}  \;
```

Again, make sure you back up everything before running such a command.

After all that, instead of generating all sizes again, you can use [OTF Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/otf-regenerate-thumbnails/).

This plugin behaves similarly to Regenerate Thumbnails except that images are resized automatically / on the fly, when they are used. Once created, they won't be processed again.

Cheers!

Comment: This still leaves the old size data in the database

Comment: This solution is the best for those who regenerated images using wp-cli then needed to remove old sizes from webp folder created previously by converter for media. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using command line

```
shopt -s globstar 
rm  -- **/*{70x70.png,90x90.png,120x79.png,120x80.png,120x120.png,120x101.jpg,150x150.png,200x180.png,300x199.png,300x251.png}
rm  -- **/*{70x70.jpg,90x90.jpg,120x79.jpg,120x80.jpg,120x120.jpg,120x101.jpg,150x150.jpg,200x180.jpg,300x199.jpg,300x251.jpg}
```

where *300x251.jpg* is your thumbnail file size .

if you want go extreemly do this `rm  -- **/*{*x*.png,*x*.jpg,*x*.jpeg,*x*.gif}`
this patter will delete all image have x at end of file name which I do not recommend .

Comment: This still leaves the old size data in the database

Comment: I think `Force Regenerate Thumbnails` plugin can solve that 'not 100% sure about that' .

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: in file functions.php

```php
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'remove_default_img_sizes', 10, 1);
function remove_default_img_sizes( $sizes ) {
  $targets = ['medium', 'medium_large','thumbnail','large', '1536x1536', '2048x2048','woocommerce_thumbnail','woocommerce_single','woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail','shop_catalog','shop_single','shop_thumbnail'];
  foreach($sizes as $size_index=>$size) {
    if(in_array($size, $targets)) {
      unset($sizes[$size_index]);
    }
  }
  return $sizes;
}
```

Step 2: Setting wp-cli link: https://wp-cli.org
[image]
file wp.bat content =>

```
@ECHO OFF
php "C:/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar" %*
```

file wp-cli.phar link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar

Step 3: Example at : use wp media regenerate --yes
[image]

Comment: I can't tell: will that delete the old thumbnails?

Comment: Even so though this is going to take time to regenerate thumbnails that don't actually need regenerating.